# Adding bullets yield OpenGL error 0x0503 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to build up my first game with cocos2d. I am trying to insert bullets. when I get this error. The problem is it only occurs when a player fires not for enemy sprites. When this error occurs no only the position of player swaps with another and back also the bullet is destroyed after hitting two targets.

```
OpenGL error 0x0503 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]
```

my weapon class has the following bullet implementation

```
if([self.bulletsArray count] <= ([self.numberOfBulletsPerFire intValue]*[self.numberOfBulletsOnScreen intValue]))
{
    for (int i =0; i< [self.numberOfBulletsPerFire intValue]; i++) {
        BulletClass *bullet = [[Bullet alloc]initWithPosition:position Direction:direction strength:self.weaponLevel spriteArray:spriteArray enemyArray:enemyArray base:base];
        [self.bulletsArray addObject:bullet];
        [self addChild:bullet];
        [bullet release];bullet = nil;
    }
}
```

in BulletClass i have the init method as :

```
(id)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)position 
        Direction:(KDirectionInput)direction 
         strength:(NSNumber *)strength 
      spriteArray:(NSMutableArray *)sprites 
       enemyArray:(NSMutableArray *)enemyArray 
             base:(CCSprite *)base{
if ((self = [super init])) {
    self.base = base;
    self.strength = strength;
    self.movementDirection = direction;
    self.spriteArray = sprites;
    self.enemyArray = enemyArray;
    self.velocity = 200/1;
    self.bullet.position = position;
    [self addChild:self.bullet z:2];
    }
    return self;
}
```

can anyone help me out here..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here that may be contributing to your problems.

First, while not a bug but more of a performance thing, you should not place `count`s and other object methods like `intValue` in your conditions, as this slows down the program. Define a local variable just before your loops that equals this number, and then use that variable in the loop so the software doesn't have count the same array or extract the same value over and over again every time it loops.

More importantly, I do not see anywhere that you are using a sprite frame cache (sprite batch), and if you are using sprite arrays that are very large where your array counts are high and manipulating and drawing these sprites many times as is typically requested by bullet operations, you could be adding a lot of burden to OpenGL unnecessarily, perhaps creating the buffer error you saw.

You should use a cocos sprite batch for your sprite arrays and give this another try; at the very least it will vastly improve the program's performance for bullet operations.